# HTTP SOAP Post Request

Tags: java, soap, cxf, mule

I need to send HTTP Request to publish  some data in a WS

E.g:

```
http://localhost:8081/hello/publishAMANSequence/filter/sequenceGenerationTime=1696-09-01T00:00:00Z&AMANId=B1&landingSequenceEntry=11234567890EST
```

I take this fault from server:

```
 Parameter should be ordered in the following sequence: [sequenceGenerationTime, AMANId, landingSequenceEntry]
```

I'm doing something wrong in the order?

mule flow:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
<flow name="jmsFlow1" doc:name="jmsFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="hello" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP" serviceClass="aero.itec.amansequenceservice.AMANSequenceInfo"/>
    <component  doc:name="Java" class="implementations.AMANSequenceImpl"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint  queue="StudioIN" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Since we don't know the server code - impossible to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this tutorial](http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/mule-3-3-rc3-building-and-consuming-web-services/) ~

I create a flow for publish the WS , that have an inbound-endpoint where I do the request

**publish.flow:**

```
 <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>  
 <flow name="jmsFlow1" doc:name="jmsFlow1">

    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="hello" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP" serviceClass="aero.itec.amansequenceservice.AMANSequenceInfo" >
        <cxf:jaxb-databinding/>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:jaxws-service>

    <component  doc:name="Java" class="implementations.AMANSequenceImpl"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint  queue="StudioIN" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" doc:name="JMS"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Then I create a client.class where I set the variable values:

**client.java**

```
public class AMANwsClient  extends AbstractTransformer{

@Override
protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc)
        throws TransformerException {
     AMANSequence sequence = new AMANSequence();


    XMLGregorianCalendar fec;
    sequence.setSequenceGenerationTime(fec);
    sequence.setAMANId("AA");
    System.out.println(sequence);
    return sequence;
}
```

This class is used like a transformer, we don't need to pass parameters in the url, only need to connect to the endpoint URL

Finally, create a **client.flow**

```
<custom-transformer class="implementations.AMANwsClient" name="AMANwsClient" />
    <flow name="csvPublisher">

       <transformer ref="AMANwsClient" />
   <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
       <outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:63081/hello" exchange-pattern="request-response">

           <cxf:jaxws-client clientClass="aero.itec.amansequenceservice.AMANSequenceInfo_Service" port="AMANSequenceInfoService" operation="publishAMANSequence">
               <cxf:inInterceptors>
                  <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
               </cxf:inInterceptors>
               <cxf:outInterceptors>
                  <spring:bean class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />
               </cxf:outInterceptors>
          </cxf:jaxws-client>

         </outbound-endpoint>

</flow>
```

Now I can save the payload into a JMS Queue and reproduce the payload from Browser, console and JMS.

If you have some suggestion to improve program performance, I'm open to listen to it.

Answer (score 1):

The url which you have provided is wrong. There should be a questionmark(?) after "filter". Then only it will consider it as parameters

```
http://localhost:8081/hello/publishAMANSequence/filter?sequenceGenerationTime=1696-09-01T00:00:00Z&AMANId=B1&landingSequenceEntry=11234567890EST
```

Moreover if you are trying to access a webservice you can't do that with a HTTP GET. You need to send it as a SOAP request. You can use APIs like CXF, AXIS etc.

Comment: im trying to do something like this: http://training.middlewareschool.com/mule/soap-code-first-build/ but with multiple values

Comment: Mule ESB is a framework to develop webservices. That link just has info to publish a webservice. How are you invoking the service? Have you written a WS client for that

Comment: i generate client with wsimport , and create an implementation to pass arguments to this WebService.

Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite sure. I haven't used Mule ESB till now. May be this link can help you http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+a+Web+Service+Client+Directly

Answer (score 0):

Put `http://localhost:8081/hello?wsdl` in **SOAPUI** ... It will create the request and response there ... then you can pass the values in the request and invoke the webservice ...
Please check the following for your reference :-
http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/Webservice-testing-with-soapUI and http://quicksoftwaretesting.com/soapui-web-service-testing-tool/